# Joins queries in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I am trying to run a joins query in rails. I am trying to output specific data from my User model while also getting data from my contactDetails model.. Code:

```
User.where(user_type: :lender).all.each do |user|
      result <<
          "#{user.id}, " +
          "#{user.contact_details},"
    end
```

The above prints out fine but when I add:

```
User.where(user_type: :lender).all.each do |user|
      result <<
          "#{user.id}, " +
          "#{user.contact_details}," +
          "#{user.contact_details.city}," +
          "#{user.contact_details.region}, " 
    end
```

Cannot find region or city.

Comment: did you try to check what `user.contact_details` prints? you should check logs and debug your code before posting on stackoverflow

Comment: I am debugging with byebug

Comment: User and ContactDetails are assciated through a has_one relationship I want to print out a Users Country, City and Region which are housed in the ContactDetails Active Record

Comment: I think you mean one user has one contact details, so this should be `user.contact_detail.city`, I think you need to check models and relationship between them again, read here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: I know what the relationship is between them user.contact_details.city still gives a NoMethodError

Comment: @RaviMariya, if that were the case then surely calling `user.contact_details` would throw an error? It sounds to me like the relationship is missing in this case, though not necessarily incorrectly setup - in which case the error will be `NoMethodError for nil:NilClass`. Have added an answer to this effect below.

Comment: Also, although I'm not sure how the inflector handles this, I'd say having one set of `contact_details` is the correct use, rather than one `contact_detail`.

Comment: Yes i mistaken the contact_details must be returning multiple records, and yes i have gone through your answer 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what's happening is `user.contact_details` is returning `nil`.

That would allow the first interpolation to work, as `"#{nil}"` just returns an empty string.

However, in the second example, when you call `user.contact_details.city` and `user.contact_details.region`, you're calling the methods `city` and `region` on `nil`, hence the error.

You can account for this using the safe operator to return empty strings, i.e.

```
user.contact_details&.city
# or in older Ruby versions
user.contact_details.try(:city)
```

Whether you want to have empty strings returned when the association exists is up to you, however, if you don't want them adding you could do something like:

```
result_string = user.id.to_s

if user.contact_details.present?
  result_string += "#{user.contact_details}," +
                   "#{user.contact_details.city}," +
                   "#{user.contact_details.region}, "
end

result << result_string
```

Finally, if you're expecting `contact_details` to be present, the problem likely lies in their creation and attachment to the `user` model - if that's the case, I'd suggest having a look at how you're doing this, and opening a new question with the relevant info if you can't get it to work.

Hope that helps - let me know if you've any questions on this at all.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this using present? method and then placing Ternary operators inside the code to a none applicable message for users who have not provided contact details. There was no need to add includes or joins:

```
User.where(user_type: :lender).all.each do |user|

      result <<
          "#{user.id}, " +
          "#{user.contact_details.present? ? user.contact_details.country : ' N/A '}," +
          "#{user.contact_details.present? ? user.contact_details.region : ' N/A ' }," +
          "#{user.contact_details.present? ? user.contact_details.city : ' N/A '}"
    end
```

Comment: Glad to hear it @Llanod11. If you think my answer helped, feel free to accept it as the answer :) One quick note - it would actually be beneficial to add `User.includes(:contact_details).where(user_type: :lender)` into your code, to avoid an [N + 1](https://semaphoreci.com/blog/2017/08/09/faster-rails-eliminating-n-plus-one-queries.html) query issue. You'll not notice it breaking your code, but that addition stops your db getting hit for every product, rather loading all the data at once.